# Single quote ' in user name & email

Tags: single-sign-on

I am using SSO from a portal to a Rails application.
The problem here is the user who has a single quote in firstname and in email also.

Example: `o'mara patti`; `patti.o'mara@example.com`.

The user is successful in logging into portal, but when she clicks on the Rails application link,
the user is getting an error saying please access the application using the SSO.
The portal is on a different server and the Rails application is on Amazon EC2 server using Tomcat6.

Can anyone just tell me how to resolve this?
Do we need encode & decode it if so where exactly I need to make the changes?

Comment: I don't know what your SSO is but if it's having problems with simple cases like that you can be fairly certain there are other more serious security issues with it.

Comment: Such user names are an acid test for whether your system is fully functional.  You can throw in an alias: `patti."the superb".o'mara@example.com` to further stress the systems.  Then you're ready to move on to other international code sets, etc.